# Is there a way to generate a gif in python without consuming an excessive amount of RAM?

Tags: python, matplotlib, optimization, gif, ram

I'm writing a little application to generate a GIF from a kifu file (it's a type of file used to save a game in Japanese chess). I'm using Matplotlib currently to draw the board and the pieces, and the matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation class combined with numpngw.AnimatedPNGWriter to write the gif. However, it uses more than 800MB of RAM to generate a single gif with 80 frames. After reflection, this value seems not surprising, because (from my understanding), each frame has a dimension of 1700x1000 and is in color. So, to keep every frame in frame, it needs a minimum of 1700*1000*80*(nb_bytes by pixel), which is a huge amount of RAM.

Is there a way to minimize this amount either with matplotlib or with another library? I suppose I need to compress frames after creating them instead of keeping them raw but I can't figure out how to do that.

Thank you very much

Comment: This is an interesting question IMO but I would post your current code as well. Maybe someone more versed in matplotlib internals can provide recommendations.

Comment: Exactly, add whatever code you have. Also, you can save frames to disk in /tmp/ and then combine them, so at most you will be using memory for 1 frame.

Comment: De you prefer that I directly paste my code here or add a link to the file in the github repository?

Comment: To not store everything in ram save individual png files of each frame and then assemble as a gif with an external program.